# Can I make function which find for me divisible by x and y in range w,z

Tags: function, range

I want to make a function that finds numbers divisible by *x* and *y* in range *w* to *z*. For example this one works:

```
T = []
for i in range(1500,2701):
   if (i % 7 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0):
       T.append(str(i))
print('\n'.join(T))
```

Question is can I make all from above in function where I can change range and divisible by:

```
x=input("range from")
y=input("range to")
w=input("divisible  by")
z=input("divisible  by")

def divisible(x,y,w,z):
    for i in range(x,y):
   if (i % w == 0) and (i % z == 0):
       T.append(str(i))
       return T
print('\n'.join(T))


def divisible(x,y,w,z):
    T=[]
    for i in range(x,y):
        if (i % w == 0) and (i % z == 0):
            T.append(str(i))
        return ('\n'.join(T))

print(divisible(1500,2701,5,7))
```

These two attempts doesn't work, any idea why? I'm beginner and any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation matters in Python. You're returning T right after you find the first divisible number. You have to return when the loop ends. Change to:

```
def divisible(x,y,w,z):
    for i in range(x,y):
        if (i % w == 0) and (i % z == 0):
           T.append(str(i))
    return T
```

Answer (score 0):

Now is working

```
x=int(input("range from"))
y=int(input("range to"))
w=int(input("divisible  by"))
z=int(input("divisible  by"))

def divisible(x,y,w,z):
    T=[]
    for i in range(x,y):
        if (i % w == 0) and (i % z == 0):
            T.append(str(i))
    return T
print(divisible(x,y,w,z))
```